# Is it posible to use switch to change value of type char function from a float function?

Tags: c

I want to use a get choice function to let user choose a letter from a menue, and i want to use this value to switch it in a float function...i know its only possible to use switch as type int, but will the value i will get is going to be float?

> float calc(float number1, float number2)
>
> {
>       int answer = get_choice();
>
> ```
> switch (answer)
>     {
>         case 'a':
>             answer = number1 + number2;
>             break;
>         case 's':
>             answer = number1 - number2;
>             break;
>         case 'm':
>             answer = number1 * number2;
>             break;
>         case 'd':
>             answer = number1 / number2;
>             break;
>     }
> return answer; }
> ```
>
> char get_choice(void)
>
> {
>       int choice;
>
> ```
> printf("Enter the operation of your choice:\n");
> printf("a. add        s. subtract\n");
> printf("m. multiply   d. divide\n");
> printf("q. quit\n");
>
> while ((choice = getchar()) == 1 && choice != 'q')
> {
>
>     if (choice != 'a' || choice != 's' || choice != 'm' || choice != 'd')
>     {
>         printf("Enter the operation of your choice:\n");
>         printf("a. add        s. subtract\n");
>         printf("m. multiply   d. divide\n");
>         printf("q. quit\n");
>         continue;
>     }
>
>
> }
> return choice; }
> ```

Comment: In the `if`, you should replace the `||`s with `&&`s, or you will never go into the body.

Comment: than you @DanielHershcovich

Comment: but if i want the user to have the option of any of these letters isn't it ||? if i will do && will it not hav to be all of them together? @DanielHershcovich

Comment: With `||` it's always `true`, as `choice` will always be different from at least one option. With `&&` it will mean "`choice` is different from all options", or "`choice` is neither 'a', 's', 'm' or 'd'".

Comment: Also, if we're talking, you shouldn't duplicate the `printf`s: you could do `int choice; do { prints...; getchar...; } while (...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float calc(float number1, float number2)

{ int choice = get_choice();
  float answer = 0.0;

  switch (choice)
```

There is no need to reuse the variable. You can also switch a `char` variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Any non-zero value is true so you should code

```
while ((choice = getchar()) != EOF && choice != 'q')
```

Comment: thanks, but why is the program not quitting when i give it the input 'q'? @ BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: You really should take habit to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and learn to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux). Both are mandatory skills when coding in *C* ...